# Drupal Advanced Analytics

Tags: 7

I need to do some advanced analytics for my site. I need the basics Google Analytics stats (nb visits, bouncing rate, etc) and how many times each particular users came back in a specific period of time.

For example, I need to answer these specific questions:

- How many users came back more that 2 times during the last week?
- How many users added two nodes or more in the last month?
- Graphs showing users repartition between fans, average users, first time users, etc

Is there any module implementing that kind of funneling in Drupal? Ideally, it should interface with Google Analytics (with Google Analytics events tracker) and/or Mixpanel.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use custom variables within Google Analytics. That way you can get all your sexy graphs in one easy place.

You would have to use existing tokens or create some new ones and attach them to your users report to Google.

You can then install : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

This shows you what variables are being tracked. For example I track my users on what content type they are viewing, what taxonomy, tags, roles etc.

What you are asking for is very specific, so I think you would end up creating custom tokens.

As an example you could show all first time users by attaching the token [user-created-date] then filter in GA to only show today's date for that custom variable.

Comment: Thanks for that! I will try that and see what I manage to do;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried taking a look at [Google Analytics Counter](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter)?

It integrates with Google Analytics & its API

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I don't see how I could implement it to answer my specific questions. Any idea?